# Laravel Nova save file as base64

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

with Laravel Nova you can Upload files with: `File::make()` for example.
But this only can be saved to a disk.
What I want is to save the uploaded file as a Base64 string in the database.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/file-fields.html#customizing-file-storage
you need to configure custom saving for the "File" field.

```php
    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            ...
            File::make('imagedata')->store(
                 function (NovaRequest $request, $model) {
                    return [
                        'imagedata' => base64_encode($request->imagedata->get())
                    ];             
                })
        ];
    }
```

In the above example `imagedate` is the field of the table where I want to save the base64 encoding.

To display the content as an image just add `thumbnail`:

```php
    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            ...
            File::make('imagedata')->store(
                 function (NovaRequest $request, $model) {
                    return [
                        'imagedata' => base64_encode($request->imagedata->get())
                    ];             
                })->thumbnail(function($value, $disk) {
                    return 'data: image/png;base64,' . $value;
            })
        ];
    }
```